# How to test a method that's using a static factory?

Tags: php, unit-testing

Now that..I'm using IoC container and DI with all my projects, I would like to learn how I should have tested my codes when I was using a static factory (I didn't do any unit testing back then). Let's say I have the following code snippet.

```
class TestFactory {

    public static function create($something) {
        switch($something) {
            case 1:
                return Dummy;
                break;
        }
    }

}

class Client {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->aClass = TestFactory::create(1);

    }

}
```

If I want to unit test **Client** class, how do I do that without using DI or IoC container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways:

1. Make sure you TestFactory is running fine with the test framework and just test Client with TestFactory running. (recommended)
2. Inherit Client class and have __construct() return a dummy object if you must separate the Client as a separate test case.